# Groupby and subsetting rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to filter my dataframe.

My dataframe

```
  Col1    col2
0    A  event1
1    A  event2
2    A  event3
3    A  event2
4    B  event1
5    B  event3
6    B  event2
7    B  event2
```

The output dataframe

```
  Col1    col2
     A  event1
     B  event1
     B  event3
```

It should return the rows before event2  for each group.
so far i tried

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x :x[0:x[x['col2'] == 'event2'].index[0]])
```

But it's not returning the required rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `groupby` and `cumsum`, followed by a final filtering step:

```
df[df.col2.eq('event2').groupby(df.Col1).cumsum().eq(0)]

  Col1    col2
0    A  event1
4    B  event1
5    B  event3
```

To reset the index to a monotonically increasing range, use

```
df[df.col2.eq('event2').groupby(df.Col1).cumsum().eq(0)].reset_index(drop=True)

  Col1    col2
0    A  event1
1    B  event1
2    B  event3
```

---

Scott Boston suggests a nice improvement to the solution above using `cumprod` on a boolean mask. The principle is the same, but is more clean:

```
df[df.col2.ne('event2').groupby(df.Col1).cumprod()]

  Col1    col2
0    A  event1
4    B  event1
5    B  event3
```

---

`groupby` + `idxmax` based filtering suggested by W-B:

```
df[df.index < df.col2.eq('event2').groupby(df.Col1).transform('idxmax')]

  Col1    col2
0    A  event1
4    B  event1
5    B  event3
```

Comment: I gotcha by one less method.   `df[df.col2.ne('event2').groupby(df.Col1).cumprod()]`

Comment: @ScottBoston Amazing. Didn't know you could use cumprod with bool values like that. May I?

Comment: This is nice :-)

Comment: Would you like adding this one as well `df[df.index<df.col2.eq('event2').groupby(df.Col1).transform('idxmax')]
`

Comment: @W-B Thanks man :) It is a different method, please add an answer and I'll be sure to upvote.